# Prove $∇(∇^i a_n) = ∇^{i+1} a_n $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that $$∇(∇^i a_n) = ∇^{i+1} a_n $$

-I'm brand new to the del operator, and unsure of how to utilize it/ work with it in this proof, any help is appreciated.

Comment: maybe some additional background to your question would be helpful.

Comment: This was literally all that was provided with this question, no hints or formulas to use unfortunately.

Comment: So, you haven't defined or discussed $\nabla$ in class? I'm not sure what $\nabla (\nabla^i a_n)$ means.

Comment: No we have not, I googled it and basically understood it as a standard derivative, still not sure how to use this to prove this problem.

Comment: Well, if it's just like $d/dx$ then I don't see what there is to prove since this iterative formula is the definition of the $(i+1)$-fold derivative... so, I wonder what else there is to the statement of the problem. The del-operator, the one I know, converts a scalar to a vector field, so, $\nabla^2 f = \nabla \cdot \nabla f$ which is a combination of the gradient and divergence operations. I guess $\nabla^3$ could mean the gradient of the function $\nabla^2 f$ and then $\nabla^4$ could be the divergence of that gradient. So, the powers would oscillate between vectors and scalars...

Comment: I'm sorry I really can't visualize what you're saying.

Comment: Is this formula something that may be of use $∇(fg) = f∇g + g∇f$

LHS: = $∇(∇^{i}a_{n})$

 = $(∇^{i})(∇)(a_{n}) + (∇^{i})(∇)(a_{n})$

= $(∇^{i+1})(a_{n})$

Does this seem correct/logical?